# Converting 'string' to a function/gate in QisKit

Tags: qiskit, programming, circuit-construction

I want to give a list of Quantum gates in a .txt file from user an apply them to a Quantum circuit but the gates in notepad .txt file have 'string' type while in Qiskit I need functions/methods. For example:
In .txt file:
'h(0)'
In Qiskit:
qc=QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.h(0)
Which is a method.
What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You could try mapping the string input to the function using a dictionary somewhat like what is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719466/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-function-name-in-python).

So considering that your text file has : `h(0)` as text, you could declare a dictionary in python as : `my_functions = {"h(0)":qc.h(0)}` to map string input to function

And in the python script, suppose variable `x` stores the text `h[0]` which is retrieved from the text file, to apply the h gate on the quantum circuit, you will just need to do:

```
my_functions[x]
```

In a nutshell, the code should be:

```
qc = QuantumCircuit(2, 2) # makes a quantum circuit with 2 qubits
my_functions = {"h(0)":qc.h(0)} # maps the string input to function call
x = "h(0)"
my_functions[x]  ## this will implement h gate on the first qubit
```